# Usage of Exclamation mark in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to Javascript. I am trying to understand the following lines of my `main.js` file:

```
define([ 'shader!vertShader.vert',
         'shader!compShader.frag',
         'myJSLib/MyJSLib'
        ],
function( vertShader,
          compShader,
          MyJSLib
          ){
"use strict" ;
```

My understanding is that `'shader!vertShader.vert'` will be assigned to `vertShader` and `'shader!compShader.frag'` to `compShader` and  `'myJSLib/MyJSLib'` to `myJSLib`.

I would like to understand what the exclamation mark does in `shader!vertShader.vert`. My Google search all shows `!` is the negation operator, which does not seems to be the case here.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927532/migrating-a-webgl-code-from-linux-to-windows

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Migrating a WebGL Code from Linux to Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57927532/migrating-a-webgl-code-from-linux-to-windows)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example of [AMD modules](https://requirejs.org/docs/whyamd.html), which have their own format for organizing JS modules/libraries. You are correct in that each of the array arguments map to the corresponding function argument.

In this case this is using a shader language and the `!` bang symbol refers to different sections of a shader file (used for graphics in things like WebGL) (specifically a vertex shader and a fragment shader, respectively).

Comment: Thank you@jake2389. It is used in WebGL. Is it OS dependent? Because it works in my Ubuntu 16 but not in Windows 10. As a side question, if instead of AMD it was NVIDIA, would `'shader!vertShader.vert'` need to be modified?

Comment: I haven't worked with WebGL much, but I'm pretty sure it's OS independent. Note that this code looks like bundled code (through something like [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)), which is not the original source code, so that might be interesting to you.

Comment: And no, AMD in this context (if you read the link) does not refer to the graphics company Advanced Micro Devices but to **Asynchronous Module Definition**. The link provides a great starting point and a link to the [actual spec](https://github.com/amdjs/amdjs-api/wiki/AMD).